# Adding new input fileds for attributes in a specific attribute group - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-attribute, custom-attributes, attribute-set

I created a new attribute group 'Features' in the products section. I need to create two new fields (checkbox and text field) apart from the available option for attributes inside the group 'Features'. I am a beginner in Magento so any help is really appreciated.

***Note: I need those extra fields for attributes inside the group 'Features' only***

Thanks in advance.

[image: Please check this screenshot]